# Jenkins Git Publisher not working with Multiple SCM plugin

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-flow

I have a use case where I have a promotion which will trigger a build from the integration branch after merging from the developer branch. I would like to push the merged changes back to the remote repository on github into the integration branch. My code is built from two different git repos using the multiple SCM plugin and the Git Publisher fails with the following stack trace. I am trying to get the git flow implemented in the jenkins workflow. Developers will always push to the developer branch and execute the promotion when they would like to merge with integration for testing. Another promotion will be executed when testing is complete and the changes need to be merged into master from where a release build will be executed. How do I achieve this using Jenkins?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM cannot be cast to hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:778)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:58)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:74)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM cannot be cast to hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM
at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(GitPublisher.java:548)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
... 69 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, Git publish doesn't support Multiple SCM. If you really need this, you can create a script to cd in each directory e place the tag and push it.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13779